# ASP.NET Core + Identity Server + Angular over HTTP

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm using the ASP.NET Core 5 + Angular + Individual auth template.

My problem is with login when serving on plain HTTP.  I keep getting redirected back to the login page after logging in with logs showing message "No user present in authorize request".

This message is spewed from IdentityServer 4's `src\IdentityServer4\src\Endpoints\AuthorizeEndpointBase.cs` file in `ProcessAuthorizeRequestAsync()`.

Is there a way to get this to work over HTTP?

### Steps to reproduce.

1. Create new project ASP.NET Core

   - .NET Core 5
   - Auth Type: Individual Accounts
   - Configure for HTTPS: No
2. Update project debug settings and uncheck `Enable SSL`
3. Start project -> Register -> Create user account
4. Login - you get routed back to the login page after supplying a valid username/password

### Additional context

There are and will be questions why not just use HTTPS.  This is for an internal application which won't be setup with SSL for the first few months, hence the need to get this to run over HTTP.

Comment: Need more data. Your configuration, the exact error message, steps you took. Please try to be complete.

Comment: Since no reasonable person would imagine one doing auth over HTTP I'm pretty sure all cookies involved in the flow are HTTPS only... Get any tool that captures/modifies traffic (Fiddler is on option) and confirm - than [edit] post with the info... Side note: realistically I don't see this post to be useful so expect some downvotes along the way...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the feedback. I have updated the question with context.  I agree that HTTPS should be default, however I am in a situation where that won't be available soon enough.